# Why is this regex not excluding these expression inside the Zero-width positive lookbehind assertion?

Tags: c#, regex

My regex is

```
(?<=signed( out)?( by)?( resident)?( by resident)?( out by)?)[:]? \S+
```

My sample strings are

```
1) ***Signed Out***      name name n,
2) signed by resident: name 
3) signed by:name name
4) Signed Out By name, name p.
```

I was expecting since I used ?<= that everything in that group would not be matched, but instead I find that some sub expressions are included in the match

For example the parts that are excluded for each string is just the string 'signed'  however I would also like to exclude from the match the 'out', 'by resident' 'by' or 'out by'  if they occur after the string signed.

Comment: Lookbehinds cannot contain quantifiers, so yours is invalid.

Comment: @BrianStephens c# does.

Comment: @AvinashRaj: sorry, I didn't realize that

Comment: @BrianStephens why sorry? Learn from mistakes, like all did :-)

Answer (score 1):

Why not forget the lookbehinds and instead use a matching group for just the part you want (the name at the end). See this example on [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/bQ1pJ0/2):

`[*]*signed(?: out)?(?: by)?(?: resident)?[*]*:? *(.*)`

Besides the changes from lookbehinds to non-capturing groups, here are the other corrections I've made:

- it looks like you need to allow for asterisks
- the colon may have 0 to many spaces after it
- the full name can't be matched by `\S+` because it may have spaces and commas

Comment: this expression seems to match the entire string, although on regex101 it works (except for javascript version)

Comment: Yes, but the *matching group* has just what you want.

Comment: could I use a MatchEvaluator to specify the group I want for this regex?  I ask this because in my program I have a list of strings (regular expressions)  that I cycle through in a loop.on each iteration  I pass the string expression to the static Regex replace method.  I could store the expression and its match evaluator and pass both.  What do you think?

Comment: @erotavlas: You don't need a MatchEvaluator, just a replacement string. So for each iteration, use the regex and replacement that goes with it. In this case, use the regex I specified and the replacement would be `$1`.

Comment: What is $1?  I haven't seen this before in a replacement string.Actually, never mind I found it - it's called Substitution in the MSDN reference

Comment: It's called a substitution, and references any of the capture groups from the regex match, in numerical order. See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ewy2t5e0%28v=vs.110%29.aspx.

Comment: Is it possible to replace the group with another string?  So far I'm only able to strip it away.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/85468/discussion-between-brian-stephens-and-erotavlas).

Answer (score 0):

Change your regex like below.

```
(?<=signed(?:(?: out)?(?: by)?|by resident)?[:]?\s*)\w+
```